# Nested YAML for hiera in puppet

Tags: yaml, puppet, hiera

I am working on designing a puppet architecture for our company.  I really like the idea of hiera and YAML files to classify my nodes.  However, I would really like to be able to either apply YAML files that aren't based on facts or import YAML files into another YAML file.

For example NodeA.yaml

```
---
include webserver.yaml
include public.yaml

classes:
etc. . .
```

This would allow me to reuse my code as much as possible. That way when I make a change to my web server configs, I only have to do it in one file instead of every node's YAML file.

I'm open to other solutions as well.

Comment: @kkamilpl has it right: the problem you say you want to address is best handled by proper definition and use of your hiera hierarchy.  Indeed, in many respects that provides an externally-directed means of doing *exactly* what you propose, as it can cause hiera to consider multiple data files together, some more specific to the current node than others.  You do not necessarily need custom facts to make it work, though it might be helpful to pair this with ENC-set global variables.

Answer (score 3):

- YAML does not support import or include
- (not recomended) You can use [loadyaml](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib#loadyaml) from [stdlib](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib) module to achieve desired functionality. Check this [example](https://puppetlabs.com/blog/module-of-the-week-puppetlabs-stdlib-puppet-labs-standard-library-part-4) of using `loadyaml` function.
- You can easily achieve expected functionality just by designing a proper `hiera` hierarchy. I do not understand why you do not want to use `facter facts`? e.g: on each node define custom facter fact `location`. Next define a hiera hierarchy:

  ```
  :hierarchy:
    - "%{::location}"/"%{::fqdn}"
    - "%{::location}"/common
    - common
  ```

  Next in file `location_1/node1.yaml` you define data specific only for that node1. In file `location_1/common.yaml` you define data common for **all** nodes in `location_1`. In `common.yaml` you define data common for all nodes. 
  If some data is common for all nodes you define it once in `common.yaml` and that's all. You **do not have to** redundantly define it in every node's yaml file.

Comment: The problem is that our managers want all of the node information stored on the master.  They don't want a node to be able to change any information about itself.

Comment: But except custom facts all node informations will be stored on master. So maybe just put all necessary informations to common.yaml.

Comment: It seems to be the best way to adapt the hiera.yaml, but in my case there is no way to change that as it is managed by another team (I asked to add some more levels relevant to our platform). Unfortunately we have to copy-paste the same values in all nodes due to this limitation.